# Problems connecting to python interpreter in vscode

Tags: python, git, visual-studio-code, azure-devops

I am not sure if this has anything to do with the fact that I am cloning a repo before starting, but I have cloned from AzureDevOps and then am having this problem.  **When I run python in VSCode from scratch I have no issue.**

Steps:

1. Create new project/repo
2. Clone in VSCode
3. save a file.ipynb
4. Run `import matplotlib`

I get the output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-0484cd13f94d> in <module>()
----> 1 import matplotlib

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

I am running the python interpreter and can see at the bottom on VSCode "Python 3.7.6 64-bit (conda)"

If I open the terminal and try run `python` I see:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site.py", line 168, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywin32_bootstrap'

Remainder of file ignored
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32

Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation
```

I can't figure out how to fix this! plz help.

Answer (score 0):

**1.Activate the environment:**

If you use powershell, pressing **Ctrl+Shift+`** can open a terminal, at the same time the conda environment will be activated. If not, manually run the command:

```
    conda activate base
```

**2.Install the required module:**

```
    pip install matplotlib
```

Pay attention to choose the same one interpreter for jupyter

[image]

Comment: ICan try activating the different environment tomorrow but this is the base environment from conda and has matplotlib already installed.  This environment works when I open a fresh VS code project but doesn’t work after I clone a repo.

Comment: can you post the repo link for me to reproduce your error

Comment: So I tried to use the shell to `conda activate base` but get the error `CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
If using 'conda activate' from a batch script, change your
invocation to 'CALL conda.bat activate'.

To initialize your shell, run`  I do try to use the `pip install matplotlib` command but also get the same output as you that the requirement is already satisfied.  The ModuleNotFoundError persists though when trying to import it.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot share the repo as it is a private work repo for my company.  This error does not occur on my personal PC though.  It seems to have something to do with my work PC restrictions? I am a non admin user.  We use applocker as well.

Comment: I tried a workaround to connect to a local jupyter notebook server which I started from the Anaconda Prompt.  I enter the URI and token into VS Code but cannot connect.  I get a permission denied error in the Anaconda Prompt Window.

Comment: can you post the terminal screenshots about the error when running `conda activate base`.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. I ended up trying to edit my path variables and still couldn’t get anything working. In the end I reinstalled anaconda and that finally worked. I’m not sure what the problem was but that fixed it.

Comment: Um, that'okay, glad to know your question has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalled and reinstalled Anaconda. Not sure what the issue was but this solved it.